# Pappus theorem and surface area of spherical zone

Tags: geometry, spheres

I'm trying to use Pappus's theorem to find the surface area of a spherical zone of radius, say, *a* and height *a/2*. According to the formula for spherical zone *2*$\pi rh$, the surface area should be $\pi a^2$.

However, when using Pappus's theorem and having determined that the circular arc length from height 0 to height *a/2* is$\ (1/6)$$\pi a$. I multiplied this by circumference *2*$\pi a$ resulting in a surface area of$\ (1/3)$$\pi^2 a^2$, which is off by 4.5%. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you explain why you think your calculation of the surface-bound "radius" multiplied by the circumference should give the area? Note that on a normal flat circle, the radius times the circumference gives twice the area of the circle.

Comment: It's not radius. It is the arc length as calculated by $\ S = r \theta$. And it is my intuition to multiply this arc length by the great circle circumference to get the  lateral surface area formed by revolving this arc around the central axis.

Comment: You have two errors. The $r$ in the formula for the surface area of a spherical cap is the radius of the sphere, not the radius of the base of the cap. Secondly, To apply [Pappus's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) you need to multiply the arc length by the circumference using the radius of the centroid of the arc. You've used the radius of the outermost point of the arc.

Comment: That's it! Radius should be perpendicular distance between axis and centroid of curve. Totally missed that one. Thanks!